# android how to know which countDownTimer is working at a specific time

Tags: android

i am building an application to receive a question with four choices, i will give the user time to read the choices and then (after read) i will begin taking marks from him, the two countDownTimers are `TimeToAnswerWithFourChoices` and `TimeToReadChoices`

if the user select choice and answer while the timer to read choices i will set the `answeredTime` to zero, so how will i know which timer is working at a specific time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up two boolean variables TimeToAnswerWithFourChoicesIsRunning (or shorten this epic long variable name) and TimeToReadChoicesIsRunning.  Initialize both the variables to "false".  Put both the timers in their own methods.  When the method is started, have the corresponding boolean set to true.  When the counter finishes ticking, have it call a method to set the boolean to false.  In this manner you will be able to reliably query whether or not the timers are running.  Be sure to set your timer variables to private to that they are only changed by calling their corresponding start and stop methods.